# How to add dompdf package manually in laravel that is hosted in cpanel

Tags: laravel, package, dompdf

How to add Package manually in Laravel project which is hosted in a c-panel. I try but can't do this. Need help please.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is already listed on `laravel-dompdf` repository [here](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/175)

> As per the suggestion you can install dompdf locally via `composer`
>   and then copy the '`vendor`' dir on my your server.

Comment: I add  dompdf folder at vendor & "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.5", at composer.json but still error. It say's Class 'Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider' not found

Comment: do you have composer on local system?

Comment: Yes i have composer on my local system

Comment: @nazmulhaqued Then install dompdf package using composer on your local system then copy the vendor folder to your server